# How do you catch errors from resolvers when the source is an external website?

Tags: angular

Angular 2 has the idea of a resolver. You load your resource and then load the page. You can stop the loading by throwing an error. This works great if the resource is navigated to from another page and navigate(...).catch(...) is used, but if you navigate to the location from an external location, there is nothing to process the catch. Anyone know how to loop in the angular router to process any errors that occur?

Thanks,
Brian

Comment: To clarify this question a little bit:

I have a resolver in my router. In case of error resolving the resource, an exception is thrown. 

Case 1. This works great:  navigate("Mypage").catch(myErrorHandlingFunctionality()) 

Case 2. This does not work:
user navigates in their web browser to: http://mywebsite/mypage

Because there is no logic tied in to catch the error in case 2.

Anyone have any idea where I can put the error handling logic for case 2 since I'm not using navigate() when the user manually types the URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to my issue and figured I'd post it in case it helps someone else.

Angular 2 has an ErrorHandler api -- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ErrorHandler-class.html

This API allows you to override the default error handling in Angular so that you can implement your own solution to recover from errors. This solution can be localized to individual models of the application. Whenever an exception is thrown, it is caught and passed down to the ErrorHandler implementation for parsing.

Comment: but it does not user router or http service or any service as it gets loaded first , any info on this ? 
also handle error gets called twice.
i need to send mail